# Missing Argument Label 'coder:' in Call

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, sidebar

While trying to set up the `slideMenuController` variable in `AppDelegate`, a persistent compiler error is returned.

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
```

Here's the code.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
      window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
      let containerViewController = ContainerViewController()
      window!.rootViewController = containerViewController                   
      window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
  }
```

Error message is stated in the title.

Comment: What's the declaration of `SlideMenuController(mainViewController: leftMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController:)`?

Comment: @Larme my mistake I copied wrong code. I edited it.

Comment: Could you specify which line is causing the issue? Because enow, there is no `slideMenuController` in your code.

Comment: @Larme I specified it.

Comment: Please edit your question body and paste in the full line of the error message. This will help us debug it. Also, can you show your ContainerViewController code? Specifically any init methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying:

```
  let containerViewController = ContainerViewController()
```

So you are calling the initializer with no parameters, i.e. `init()`. But that is not how you normally instantiate a view controller. A view controller class *might* have an initializer with no parameters, but because of changes you've made to your ContainerViewController, it doesn't have that initializer.

The designated initializer for a view controller is `init(nibName:bundle:)`. So you might want to say something like this:

```
  let containerViewController = ContainerViewController(nibName:nil, bundle:nil)
```

Or, if you want to specify the nib name, go ahead and specify it instead of `nil`. But at least, if you put what I'm suggesting, your code should compile and then you can proceed further as you like.

Or, if you have defined some *other* initializer for ContainerViewController, call *that* initializer. (You have not shown how ContainerViewController is defined, so it's impossible to say; you have to look and see, since you have the code and we don't.) But you cannot call the initializer with no parameters, because it doesn't exist.